# Swagger spitting out xml response instead of json

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, swagger

I'm a week old in spring. I'm developing a pure RESTful API service using Spring + maven + Jackson. While exploring some best practices, I came across [this](http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/), so I decided I'll be using swagger with spring mvc (and swaggerUI) for documentation. I went through [this](http://ufasoli.blogspot.in/2013/06/spring-mvc-and-swagger-generating.html) and [this](http://blog.zenika.com/index.php?post/2013/07/11/Documenting-a-REST-API-with-Swagger-and-Spring-MVC) tutorial for doing what I wanted. Everything was going fine and dandy until I realized after hitting /api-docs I got XML response, as opposed to JSON response in tutorials and every-other-where. This won't work fine when I add SwaggerUI. Later I found out [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wordnik-api/5Xlhk3x_e5Y) that swaggerUI expects json. I could always go back and use swagger without server integration (https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/Adding-Swagger-to-your-API), but that won't really satisfy my needs.

Here are the contents of pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.darshandzend</groupId>
<artifactId>swjs</artifactId>
<name>swjs</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT.121130</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

servlet context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.darshandzend.swjs" />

<beans:bean class="com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.DocumentationConfig" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/swagger.properties" />
```

swagger.properties

```
documentation.services.version=1.0
documentation.services.basePath=http://localhost:8080/swjs/
```

I tried GET /api-docs/ in chrome dev http tool with "Accept" header set to "application/json", which worked. Does this mean I manually have to set request headers somewhre? I'm adding web.xml just in case.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I reckon swagger won't require any special annotations so my java codebase remains the same.

Is this question too long? Pardon me, for I'm new to SO. Please edit and suggest.

Controller class:

```
@Api(value = "contacts", description = "contacts") // Swagger annotation
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {
@ResponseBody
  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public Response select() {
    return new Response("success", "", "this is the humble abode of everything");
  }

@ResponseBody
  @RequestMapping(value="/{id}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public Response get(@PathVariable String id) {
    return new Response("Success", "", id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your Controller method?

Comment: Also, please ignore arguments in @Api annotation... code ain't very pretty

Comment: can you confirm you have the Jackson library in the classpath, preferably in the WAR?

Comment: When I hit one of the APIs I defined in controller, I sure get a JSON response. Can you suggest how else could I check that? Also, I noticed I'm using jackson from 'codehaus' and [the sample example on github](https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc-example) uses one from 'fasterxml'. Could that make the difference?

Comment: You can use curl to send requests from CLI, see if you get JSON.  Also, but breaks in your handler...make sure the one you think is being executed is actually executed.  As for where you get the Jackson libs, I don't think it matters, as long as its the right JAR.

Comment: The *codehaus* jars are for Jackson up to version 1.9.x. From version 2.0 and up, Jackson uses the *fasterxml* jars. You're probably going to want the newer versions- I see no reason to develop something now with the old ones. They don't work well together, either - if one of your dependencies uses the *fasterxml* jars, and you bring in the *codehaus* jars, it can definitely screw things up- only one Jackson engine will be loaded, not both.

Comment: @CodeChimp cURLing is what I did, actually.

Comment: @darshandzend Upgrade to the latest version 0.6.5 and as Eyal mentioned use the the fasterxml (2.x) version of jackson. Also try cURLing with accept header set to appication/json and see if that helps identify/isolate the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swagger-ui does not set an Accept header with its AJAX requests. Unfortunately swagger-springmvc returns XML if no accept header or no path extension (.json) is given.

You can manually add a JSON accept header to every request swagger-ui executes. Simply add the following JavaScript line to your swagger-ui index.html file:

```
window.authorizations.add("Accept", 
    new ApiKeyAuthorization("Accept", "application/json", "header"));
```

This is my modified index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Swagger UI</title>
  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  <link href='css/highlight.default.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  <link href='css/screen.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/shred.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src='lib/jquery-1.8.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/jquery.slideto.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/jquery.wiggle.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/handlebars-1.0.0.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/underscore-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/backbone-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/swagger.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='swagger-ui.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script src='lib/highlight.7.3.pack.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/api-docs",
      dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
      supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'],
      onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi){
        if(console) {
          console.log("Loaded SwaggerUI")
        }
        $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});
      },
      onFailure: function(data) {
        if(console) {
          console.log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
          console.log(data);
        }
      },
      docExpansion: "none"
    });

    window.authorizations.add("Accept", new ApiKeyAuthorization("Accept", "application/json", "header"));

    $('#input_apiKey').change(function() {
      var key = $('#input_apiKey')[0].value;
      console.log("key: " + key);
      if(key && key.trim() != "") {
        console.log("added key " + key);
        window.authorizations.add("key", new ApiKeyAuthorization("api_key", key, "query"));
      }
    })
    window.swaggerUi.load();
  });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='header'>
  <div class="swagger-ui-wrap">
    <a id="logo" href="http://swagger.wordnik.com">swagger</a>

    <form id='api_selector'>
      <div class='input icon-btn'>
        <img id="show-pet-store-icon" src="images/pet_store_api.png" title="Show Swagger Petstore Example Apis">
      </div>
      <div class='input icon-btn'>
        <img id="show-wordnik-dev-icon" src="images/wordnik_api.png" title="Show Wordnik Developer Apis">
      </div>
      <div class='input'><input placeholder="http://example.com/api" id="input_baseUrl" name="baseUrl" type="text"/></div>
      <div class='input'><input placeholder="api_key" id="input_apiKey" name="apiKey" type="text"/></div>
      <div class='input'><a id="explore" href="#">Explore</a></div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="message-bar" class="swagger-ui-wrap">
  &nbsp;
</div>

<div id="swagger-ui-container" class="swagger-ui-wrap">

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I remember trying that. Must've made a syntactical error that time. Anyway, this worked. Thank you.

Comment: It's astonishing that this is a bug and no one has EVER reported it upstream. I did it: https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui/issues/388

Comment: And here we have the bug fixed upstream https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-js/commit/c229433dad3a78beebdd7af512d55727906262b4 - in just 3 hours.