# Swagger(-ui) doesn't show the operations

Tags: java, spring, operation, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a spring webapp, i've aadded swagger and swagger-ui. I've added a dummy class to test swagger:

```
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.Api;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiError;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiErrors;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Api(value = "DummyController", description = "Dummy description for the controller")
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/dummy")
public class DummyClassForSwagger {

    @ApiOperation(value = "First dummy output", httpMethod = "GET")
    @ApiErrors({@ApiError(code = 404, reason = "First dummy test") })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/first", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String dummyOutputOne() {
        return "Dummy output";
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Second dummy output", httpMethod = "GET")
    @ApiErrors({@ApiError(code = 404, reason = "Second dummy test") })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/second", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String dummyOutputTwo() {
        return "Second dummy output";
    }
}
```

After build/deploy i can see the dummy class on the swagger page (see attachment [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSNQx.png)). The problem is, that "List operations" doesn't show anything. The raw output is as follow:

```
<controllerDocumentation>
<apiVersion>1.0</apiVersion>
<apis>
<description>Dummy description for the controller</description>
<operations>
<deprecated>false</deprecated>
<errorResponses>
<code>404</code>
<reason>First dummy test</reason>
</errorResponses>
<httpMethod>GET</httpMethod>
<nickname>dummyOutputOne</nickname>
<notes/>
<responseClass>String</responseClass>
<summary>First dummy output</summary>
</operations>
<path>/dummy/first</path>
</apis>
<apis>
<description>Dummy description for the controller</description>
<operations>
<deprecated>false</deprecated>
<errorResponses>
<code>404</code>
<reason>Second dummy test</reason>
</errorResponses>
<httpMethod>GET</httpMethod>
<nickname>dummyOutputTwo</nickname>
<notes/>
<responseClass>String</responseClass>
<summary>Second dummy output</summary>
</operations>
<path>/dummy/second</path>
</apis>
<basePath>http://localhost:8080/mapserver/core</basePath>
<models/>
<resourcePath>/dummy</resourcePath>
<swaggerVersion>1.0</swaggerVersion>
</controllerDocumentation>
```

I think, the problem is a missing tag "operation" or something like this...but i'm not sure (and i don't know, how to fix this). Any suggestions?

Comment: I had a similar problem and I solved it doing this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010529/swagger-spitting-out-xml-response-instead-of-json

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I was getting the error `"SwaggerOperation  handleIllegalArgumentsException is missing method."`.

After debugging I figured out my `@ExceptionHandler` methods in `Controller` class didn't have any `swagger` annotations, and this was causing the issue.

I commented my `ExceptionHandler` methods and swagger ui started working fine.

I am now figuring out which swagger annotations to use for `ExceptionHandler` methods in spring mvc.

My `ExceptionHandler` method in my controller class was:

```
@ExceptionHandler({IllegalArgumentException.class})
public ResponseEntity<?> handleIllegalArgumentsException(IllegalArgumentException e)
{
    LOGGER.error("IllegalArgumentException in user controller", e);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponseDTO("BAD_REQUEST", e.getMessage()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```